# Ubuntu: cgo: C compiler "gcc-11" not found: exec: "gcc-11": executable file not found in $PATH

Tags: go, gcc, cgo

I am using Ubuntu 20.04, and I installed Go using Homebrew.
The version of Go is go 1.19.

When I run my application with `go run .` or `go build .`, this error comes up:

```
# github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3
cgo: C compiler "gcc-11" not found: exec: "gcc-11": executable file not found in $PATH
```

I have tried running

```
sudo apt install gcc
```

but the terminal tells me that gcc is already the newest version (4:9.3.0-1ubuntu2).

When I run `gcc -v`

the terminal tells me `gcc version 9.4.0 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1)`

And I have already run `apt update` and `apt upgrade` already, and then reinstall gcc, but it's still version 9.4.0

My question is how do I install gcc-11? Or is it not supported in Ubuntu 20.04? Or should I not use go 1.19?

Thanks

Comment: The sqlite3 package does not mention `gcc-11` specifically. Can you check `go env` to see if you have set any of the C compiler variables to that binary name?

Comment: I ran go env, and found CC="gcc-11".

Comment: So unset or fix the `CC` variable in your environment

Comment: To cite [the docs](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/cgo): «The default C and C++ compilers may be changed by the CC and CXX environment variables, respectively; those environment variables may include command line options.»

Comment: @JimB Thanks, changing the CC env var fixed the problem!

Answer (score -1):

The `go` developers provide a simple way to manage multiple go versions at once: https://go.dev/doc/manage-install

It should not be too hard to explore if this is a Homebrew artifact, or something generic to `go`, or a specific version of `go` on your system.

You might also look at the output of `go env` which should list configured defaults for various dependencies. You are looking for something like `CC=gcc` in the output.

Comment: I ran go env, and found CC="gcc-11". So I need to change it to gcc-9?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Go, or the version of Go, it's a local configuration problem.

Comment: @pkdc You can either `unset CC` or invoke `go` with something like `CC=gcc go ...` and that should fix your problem. Not sure why this answer, which helped you find your problem got downvoted, but the Go questions seem to generate some negative reactions, so I guess that's ~normal.

Comment: @Tinkerer Thanks, I didn't downvote it myself, but I also didn't follow your first two advices on reading the go doc article, and exploring the several problems.